Can't pull drud/ddev-webserver docker image any more (it was deleted)
after months without any problems in running a complex ddev based installation, currently I am facing problems with starting up the project.
I did some updates to Docker and cleaning up of "orphanized" images, but now, however, the following problems came along:

I use(d) BASE_IMAGE=drud/ddev-webserver:v1.21.5 as a custom base image for several services and it worked well. But now, this image can't be found anymore (and obviously, I deleted my local one copy).
I changed to BASE_IMGAGE=ddev/ddev-webserver:v1.23.5 without success.
Than, I updating ddev to v1.23.5 and also fixed the installation of ddev and docker (also updated) to the arm64 versions, since I am running am a silicon mac. Now I was able to perform a docker pull ddev/ddev-webserver:v1.23.5 (needed to name the version, latest or stable did not work).
But however, when I do a ddev (re)start, I see the following error:

stderr='failed to solve: ddev/ddev-webserver:1.23.5: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/ddev/ddev-webserver:1.23.5: docker.io/ddev/ddev-webserver:1.23.5: not found'
This seems to be a strange result, since this URL seems not to be a valid URL at all, AND I was able to pull the image by hand, AND the image exists locally.
What am I doing wrong?

The drud/ddev-webserver Docker image has been removed, as it was really obsolete.
You have the wrong tag for docker.io/ddev/ddev-webserver. The tag should be v1.23.5.
$ docker pull ddev/ddev-webserver:v1.23.5
v1.23.5: Pulling from ddev/ddev-webserver
70ae8b869006: Downloading  91.78MB/504.2MB...

Also, please do not build your own image. Instead, please use custom extra Dockerfiles, like .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile.*. See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage
In the future, to find valid image tags, you can view them at hub.docker.com, for example, https://hub.docker.com/r/ddev/ddev-webserver/tags
